# How to hide and show elements on hover using CSS (span, onhover, selectors)?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in that I'm trying to show an `<aside>` text inline when a mouse is hovering over a defined keyword. The way I planned to do this to utilize the `<span>`, which wraps the `<aside>` and then I could use CSS selectors like `#main > article > .inline-aside, aside { display: none; }` to choose the descendant `<aside>` elements within these special purpose regions.

I seem to be able to hide the contents, but not to get them back. The problem might be, I'm a total CSS rookie, the `display: none` somehow removes the element. Is there a way to accomplish this using CSS alone?

Here are the relevant pieces and I have a fuller Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Veksi/z0d5j1xb/.

`<article id="faq-section-general" class="tab-content">
      <h1>General</h1>
      <p>The four Byzantine <span class="inline-aside">generals.<aside>General inline aside.</aside></span></p>

      <p>Some more general text.</p>
    </article>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that [you can't use `<aside>` inside of a `<p>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015809/3162554). The `<aside>` would then be moved outside of the `<p>` which changes your DOM what makes it impossible to select the `<aside>` on hover of the `.inline-aside` as [you can't go back in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655293/3162554).

However, if you change your `<p>` for example to a `<div>` the correct selector logic would look like the following:

```
/* By default, hide aside blocks that have .inline-aside elements as parents. */
#main > article .inline-aside aside {
  display: none;
}

/* Show the aside elements inside .inline-aside elements when they're hovered. */
#main > article  .inline-aside:hover aside {
  display: inline; /* or block */
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0d5j1xb/5/).

Comment: Well, this answered all the lingering doubts I had. Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try (for you code example)

```
tab-content > p > span.inline-aside:hover + aside{
  display:block/*or anything else*/
}
```

EDIT
You can also use `transition` to make things smoother, like this :

```
tab-content > p > span.inline-aside:hover + aside{
  display:block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `<aside>` element is not critical for you, you could consider using an inline element as pop-up text.

I modified your code to use another `<span>` inside the `.inline-aside` element. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/z0d5j1xb/3/

Hope that's what you needed.

Also, a general recommendation - avoid using deep nesting in CSS like `#main > article > .inline-aside`.

Answer (score 0):

you have three issues

**1**

the span is inline element but aside is a block element

you can't put a block element inside inline element

the issue is that when you do so the browser render the block element outside the inline element

you can turn span to div

**2**

your selector `>` mean a direct child not a descendant so you must include the `p` element in your selector `#main > article > p > .inline-aside` or just use the space selector `#main .inline-aside`

**3**

is that you can't hover an element with `display: none;` you should use `visibility: hidden;`

here is a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/z0d5j1xb/6/) but you can still do better

Answer (score 0):

**We can use javascript/jquery for hiding or displaying data on hover event check out the following code,, In the snippet when u hover on the generals word it will show the content**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".inline-aside" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('aside').css( 'display','initial')},function(){$('aside').css('display','none')} );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<article id="faq-section-general" class="tab-content">
      <h1>General</h1>
      <p>The four Byzantine <span class="inline-aside">generals.<aside class="a" style="display:none">General inline aside.</aside></span></p>

      <p>Some more general text.</p>
    </article>
</body>
```